# Family of planes

Tags: vectors, 3d

The equation of a plane passing through the line 
$$\frac{x-1}{1} =  \frac{y-2}{1} = \frac{z-2}{-2} $$ and making an angle of $30 ^\circ$ with the plane 
$$ x + y + z  = 5$$
is:

In the solution is assumed that the equation of plane is 
$$( x -y+1) +r(2y+z-6)=0$$
 and then by using the condition of angle between planes they find $r$ and the equation of the plane.

So please explain why did they assume such an equation of the plane and is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the equation represents a plane for all r. Each r is corresponding to a different plane. If you write the given line in parametric form and substitute into the equation, the equality holds for all r.

Comment: CY Kwong, I cannot understand how to assume this equation or can we take another equation also

Comment: both $x-y+1=0$ and $2y+z-6=0$ are planes containing the given line. So $(x-y+1)+r(2y+z-6)=0$ is a plane containing the given line for any $r$ (can be shown by substitution). The next thing to consider is whether the equation $(x-y+1)+r(2y+z-6)=0$ covers all planes containing the given line. If you consider the normal vector of this general plane, you will find that it is a linear combination of the normal vectors of $x-y+1=0$ and $2y+z-6=0$. It covers all possibilities, except the plane $2y+z-6=0$